# How to make IntelliJ scala autoformatter stop moving comments after an opening curly brace?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, autoformatting

Example:

```
package common.path

class Foobar { // why you do this?

}
```

after auto formatting this reverts to:

```
package common.path

class Foobar {
   // why you do this?

}
```

Is there anyway to cancel this specific behavior? I've been all over the settings and couldn't find anything...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No there is not a way to change this. It's because the auto formatter does not include ways to invent your own arbitrary formats, rather it only includes ways to tweak the existing accepted conventions according to the official Scala style guide.

The convention is to comment a `Class` (`Trait`, etc) like this:

```
// This class does ...
class A {
...
}
```

If you want a comment inside the class, then that should be immediately followed by a line/method that the comment is commenting on.

Comment: The class was an example, of course.
It also does this for methods, and all other curly braces, such as lambdas, catch blocks, etc.
Also, an auto formatter that does not allow you to use your own formats is a crappy formatter.